# How should I email to my interviewer to say I'd like to reschedule my interview

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do the following sentences work?

1. I'd like to reschedule my interview for ...(the new date)
2. I'd like put off my interview until ...(the new date)
3. I'd like to push back my interview until ...(the new date)

Comment: They're all fine. Or you can use a different verb *(**delay, postpone, defer,...**)* if you want.

Comment: I am more concerned with the preposition I used, are those natural?

Comment: *I'd like to delay / postpone / defer my interview **to** [new date].* We'd usually follow ***for*** by the ***original*** date. Whoever's looking after the appointments diary at the other end would need to know that, so they can find it to amend the entry. Note that you *could* quite reasonably specify both dates in the request: *I'd like to delay / postpone / defer my interview **for** [original date] **to** [new date]* (in this construction, ***on*** is interchangeable with ***for***).